# Prevent `CALayer` from dropping shadow set by its parent layer

Tags: swift, uikit, core-animation, calayer

Recently I've been playing around with shadows and one particular case got me really interested. Suppose I have a parent `CALayer` which has three oval-shaped sublayers laid in a stack. I applied shadow to the parent layer

```swift
containerLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
containerLayer.shadowRadius = 10
containerLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
```

and this is the result I got:
[image: Three oval-shaped layers laid out in stack dropping shadow]

But what if I didn't want the green oval to drop shadow? I continued the experiment and set `fillColor` of the green layer to `nil` to find out that this in fact does exclude it from combined shadow on the parent layer:
[image: Two oval-shaped layers laid out in stack dropping shadow]

So I got a question: is it possible to both prevent certain layer from dropping a shadow **AND** preserve layer `fillColor` or any of that layer's sublayers?

I've tried adding a sublayer to now invisible green oval-shaped layer, but that immediately renders the shadow underneath it. Here's how it looks:
[image: No image description provided]

Orange square is a direct sublayer of now invisible green oval.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not really what's happening, you can think of the view's layer ***casting*** **the shadow**.

That's why if we have two sublayers, one with a filled path and one with a stroked path, we get this:

[image]

That's also why, if the view's layer or background is not clear, we get this:

[image]

So, when we apply a shadow to the "root" layer, it and its sublayers are "flattened" and the shadow is applied to the non-clear portions.

For your example, if you want shadows on the red and blue layers, but not the green layer, you can apply the shadows to the individual sublayers:

[image]

[image]

You didn't say in your question whether or not you want the blue-layer shadow to appear overlapped on green. If *not*, there are a couple ways to "move it under"...

First, we can create a duplicate of the blue layer - added first - and give *that* layer a shadow instead of the "top" blue layer:

[image]

A little tough to tell, but we now have 4 sublayers:

[image]

Alternatively, we could set the shadow on the red layer, no shadow on green or blue, but then add a `.shadowPath` to the view's "root" layer:

[image]

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that it is _highly_ recommended that `shadowPath` _always_ be used whenever possible. Without going into too many technical details, render performance is improved when you explicitly tell Core Animation how to draw a shadow, and that means providing a shadow path.